# twitter4j serializable is saving but not loading

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, twitter4j

I want to save and load my twitter feed by first saving it into tweet.ser file and then using a load() method to retrieve it. But im getting an error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: twitter4j.ResponseListImpl cannot be cast to [Ltwitter4j.Status;
    at com.teamtreehouse.RealTreets.load(RealTreets.java:25)
    at Example.main(Example.java:12)"

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import twitter4j.Status;

public class RealTreets{
    public static void save(List<Status> status){
        try(
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("tweets.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        ) {
            oos.writeObject(status);
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Problem saving Tweets");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static Status[] load(){
        Status[] status = new Status[0];
        try(
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("tweets.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        ){
            status = (Status[]) ois.readObject();
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println("Error reading file!");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
            System.out.println("Error loading treets.");
            cnfe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }
}
```

And I have checked...the save is working just fine. tweets.ser is showing the data. There is a issus in the load() method.

Comment: This is because a `List<Status>` and a `Status[]` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are saving a `List<Status>` to a file, but are then trying to read it as a `Status[]`.  These are not the same thing, thus the failure.

You need to change either how you are saving it or how you are reading it, so that they are consistent with each other.

Comment: I checked and you are right, twitter.getHomeTimeLine() can only be saved into  List<Status>. So I cannot change the saving method. So I replaced all the Status[] with List<Status> and now im getting an error on the line :           List<Status> status = new Status[0] - "incompatible types: Status[] cannot be converted to List<Status>". Can you help me convert it>

Comment: As I said, a `List<Status>` and a `Status[]` are not the same thing.  You should seek an introductory tutorial on data structures.